# What, exactly, are those "things" that come from the hole in the sky in The Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

These:

[image]

They explode like something that would be mechanical running on some power source, yet they roar and attempt to eat some of the Avengers, and they move more like an animal in water than like any machine would.

So, are these things Animal, Vegetable or Mineral?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Reverse Google Image Search** immediately brings up:

[Chitauri](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Chitauri):

> The Chitauri are a cybernetic alien race governed by a hive mind and
>   subservient to the overlord Thanos. They were led by the Asgardian
>   Loki during the War for Earth but were defeated by the Avengers.
>   ...
>   The Chitauri are a powerful, reptilian warrior race, a hybrid between organic beings and machines

Furth research in that vein reveals the giant worms are [Leviathans](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Leviathan):

> Leviathans are extraterrestrial animal-slaves and warships for the
>   Chitauri. Not much about them is known, only that they are
>   cybernetically-enhanced beasts which aid the Chitauri during their
>   attempted invasion of Earth.

From the [another Chitauri wikia page](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Chitauri):

> Their troop transports take the form of the Leviathans, very large
>   serpent-like creatures. These Leviathans can carry hundreds of
>   Chitauri infantry, and are quite durable. However, they do not have
>   any weaponry aside from simply ramming their target, and are shown to
>   be vulnerable to large amounts of explosives, electricity, or kinetic
>   force.

Comment: Definitely not Chitauri, but probably Leviathan.  But they **do** launch Chitauri onto buildings at one point, which must mean they've got a mechanical exterior?

Comment: I never said they were Chitauri. That was the first result you get if you reverse image search the picture provided. I though it was pretty clear in the quotes I posted that the Leviathans are "beasts of burden" living troop ships for the Chitauri.

Comment: OK, I'm going to go ahead and just add that it appears the Leviathans have metallic plating grafted onto them, which explains why at least one of them was throwing sparks off when it crash-landed.  Also, apparently the Chitauri were carried in pods that were grafted onto the exterior of the Leviathan as well.  They are, in fact, beasts and not machines.  Source: http://marvel.wikia.com/Leviathan_(Race)